# asp.net multiple table update statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to turn this query into an update statement.  I will have to update the values from  fields.  Everything is already in place but the update statement.

Here is the select version of the query:

```
SELECT i.GoLiveDate, i.FirstBonusRun, i.TechFName, i.TechLName, i.TechEmail, i.TechPhone, i.WebISPFName, i.WebISPLName, 
              i.WebISPEmail, i.WebISPPhone, i.FullFillFName, i.FullFillLName, i.FullFillEmail, i.FullFillPhone, d.FName,
              d.LName, d.HomePhone, d.Email
              FROM NC_Information i
              INNER JOIN Distributor d
                ON d.DistID = i.ClientID
              WHERE clientID = @value
```

Is it possible to update two different tables from within the same query?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public void Update (int ClientID)
{
    using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( GeneralFunctions.GetConnectionString() ) )
    using ( var cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText =
        @"SELECT i.GoLiveDate, i.FirstBonusRun, i.TechFName, i.TechLName, i.TechEmail, i.TechPhone, i.WebISPFName, i.WebISPLName, 
          i.WebISPEmail, i.WebISPPhone, i.FullFillFName, i.FullFillLName, i.FullFillEmail, i.FullFillPhone, d.FName,
          d.LName, d.HomePhone, d.Email
          FROM NC_Information i
          INNER JOIN Distributor d
            ON d.DistID = i.ClientID
          WHERE clientID = @value";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@value", ClientID );
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope just update one table put statement.  An update statement begins with update tablename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update multiple tables in one statement, but you can use a transaction to make sure that the updates are contingent upon one another:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE SomeTable
SET SomeColumn  = 'Foo' 
WHERE SomeID = 123   

UPDATE AnotherTable
SET AnotherColumn = 'Bar'
WHERE AnotherID = 456    

COMMIT
```

Comment: I'm going to try and implement this one.  I like them being contingent upon one another.

Answer (score 0):

I think,  you cannot directly do the update on two tables. But you can `Optimize` the query.

### How?

**[OUTPUT keyword in Insert/Update/Delete Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)**

The first `Update Statement's Select Data(filtered data)` can be reused using the below mentioned example.

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
    id INT,
    employee VARCHAR(32)
)
go

INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES 
      (1, 'name1')
     ,(2, 'name2')
     ,(3, 'name3')
     ,(4, 'name4');
GO

DECLARE @GuestTable TABLE
(
    id INT,
    employee VARCHAR(32)
);

update #table1
Set id = 33
OUTPUT inserted.* INTO @GuestTable
Where id = 3
```

> The Data in the '@GuestTable' Table is filtered data and can be
>   reused.

```
select * from @GuestTable

drop table #table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a dataset with two datatables, and let the [tableadaptermanager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384426.aspx) manage the updates.